# Generate warnings for autoboxing use

Tags: java, eclipse, checkstyle, pmd, autoboxing

I would like to generate warnings for ALL autoboxing and unboxing.

Has anyone found an effective way?

**Eclipse** catches basic autoboxing errors: eg. `Integer i = null; i++`.  But fails on anything complex, and isn't really what I'm after.

I've looked at **PMD** and **Checkstyle** but couldn't find anything there.

I know it's a controversial subject, but I think it's a dangerous feature.
There's no way to disable it, so I would at least like a report to check during code reviews.

I see this `NullPointerException` far too often in code reviews and bugs:

```
class X {
    Integer i = null;

    public int doSomething() {
        return i + 2;
    }
}
```

I want to stop it from getting that far.

Comment: From your query I understand the following setting is already set in Eclipse? Am i Right? 
"Preferences->Java->Compiler->Errors/Warnings->Potential Programming Problems->Boxing and unboxing conversions"

Comment: Ah, that's perfect! Thanks. I missed that one. I only had the "Null pointer access" enabled. Please post this as an Answer :)

Comment: It would still be nice to know how to check for autoboxing using static analysis tools. Then it could be integrated into the nightly build.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Set this setting in your Eclipse,

> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> Errors/Warnings -> Potential Programming
>   Problems -> Boxing and unboxing conversions.

Comment: Hopefully they separate boxing from unboxing.  Boxing I don't mind unboxing is more dangerous: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=163065